# Need assistance testing my class

Tags: java, loops

My assignment:

The game of Stix – similar to a game played on "Survivor, Thailand" some time ago – in a simplified version somehow looks like this:

It is played by two players (in Survivor it were more than two, but here we just deal with two).
A number of sticks (like matches) are placed on a table.
The first player takes 1, 2 or 3 sticks away, provided that there that many on the table.
Then the second player takes 1, 2 or 3 sticks away (if possible), and so on.
Whoever takes the last stick, loses.

This is my class:

```
    public class StixBoard
    {
        public int number;

        public StixBoard(int number)
        {
        number = number;
        }

        public int getNumStix()
        {
        return number;
        }

        public boolean takeStix(int number)
        {
            int take = 1;
            while(take <= getNumStix())
            {
            takeStix(take);
            take++;
            }

            if(number >= 1 && number <= 3)
            {
            number = number - this.number;
                System.out.println("Number of sticks on board:" + number);
            return(true);
            }
        else
        System.out.println("Illegeal Move");
        return(false);
        }

        public boolean isGameOver()
        {
            if(number >=1)
            {
            return(true);
            }
            else
            return false;
        }

            public String toString()
        {
            return(getNumStix() + " Stix Remaining.");
        }
    }

This is my tester:

    public class StixGame
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

        StixBoard game1 = new StixBoard(6);
        System.out.println(game1.getNumStix());


        }

    }

Can someone tell my why game1 only returns 0?

*UPDATE*
Now that it constantly displays:

    6
    Illegeal Move
    false
    6

I've been playing around with it but can't figure out why =/

Program now looks like this:

public class StixBoard
{
    public int number;

    public StixBoard(int number)
    {
    this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumStix()
    {
    return number;
    }

    public boolean takeStix(int number)
    {
        int take = 0;

        while(take != number && number <= 3 && number > 0)
        {
        number = this.number - take;
        take++;
        }

        if(this.number >= 1 && this.number <= 3)
        {
        number = number - this.number;
            System.out.println("Number of sticks on board:" + number);
        return(true);
        }
    else
    System.out.println("Illegeal Move");
    return(false);
    }

    public boolean isGameOver()
    {
        if(number >=1)
        {
        return(true);
        }
        else
        return false;
    }

        public String toString()
    {
        return(getNumStix() + " Stix Remaining.");
    }
}
```

And this my tester:

```
public class StixGame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    StixBoard game1 = new StixBoard(6);
    System.out.println(game1.getNumStix());
    System.out.println(game1.takeStix(3));
    System.out.println(game1.getNumStix());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `number = number` in the constructor, it actually uses the variable from the input, so you're basically resetting that to itself. Then when the constructor finishes, it falls out of scope, so that variable disappears. What you need to do instead is either rename the function parameter or use `this.number = number`.

Comment: I just edited the answer. The guy you must thank is Yue Yuan.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your class with :

```
public StixBoard(int number)
{
this.number = number;
}
```

Avoid using same name for variables in constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor sets `number` parameter to itself:

```
public StixBoard(int number)
{
number = number;
}
```

And the default value for `this.number` remains `0`. You need to assign parameter value to instance variable using `this.` prefix to avoid name clash:

```
this.number = number;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your constructor:

```
public StixBoard(int number) {
    number = number;
}
```

Replace with:

```
public StixBoard(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

As you can see, the parameter number is shadowing your field number. So, the asignment is assigning the parameter number to itself, not to your class field. To remove the shadowing, you have to use the keyword `this` to refer to the object field executing in the current thread.